# ¿Como poner un valor inicial a Selectize.js?

Tags: javascript, select

Tengo el constructor de mi selectize.js el cual relleno con un for para las opciones que va a tener también tiene una función para agregar mas valores lo que yo quiero es que de inicio el selectize tenga un valor, en este caso son colores digamos que por default inicie con el color rojo, como lo puedo hacer.Dejo un link a un link que se puede modificar no es el mismo pero lo que busco es que con una variable es que empiece con un valor que yo le de desde js
https://codepen.io/angelmg18/pen/GRxWLgZ

```
 for (i = 0; i < get_rows.length; i++) {
            txt += `<option value='${get_rows[i].id_color}'>${get_rows[i].nombre_color}</option>`;
        }

        controlador.rowsColours(get_rows);
        document.querySelector('#s1_colour').innerHTML = txt;

        $('#s1_colour').selectize({
            sortField: 'text',
            placeholder: 'Selecciona un color',
            delimiter: ",",
            persist: false,
            create: function (input) {
                petition_vin_new_colour({
                    Id_color: 0,
                    Nombre_color: input,
                    Activo_color: true,
                    Fecha_alta: get_date_full(),
                    Usuario_alta: 1,
                    Fecha_modifico: null,
                    Usuario_modificio: 0,
                    Fecha_elimino: null,
                    Usuario_elimino: 0,
                });

                return {
                    value: input,
                    text: input,
                };
            },
        });
```